# Where can I find a Bretonian Heavy Fighter?

Tags: freelancer

I'm playing Freelancer, and I have been flying the Defender Heavy Fighter class.  Upon arriving in Bretonian I was told to buy a new ship, but I've only found ships of the Freighter and Light Fighter class.  Where can I find a Bretonian Heavy Fighter class ship?

Answer (score 4):

[Freelancer Wikia](http://freelancer.wikia.com/wiki/Bretonia_B-907A_Crusader_Heavy_Fighter) lists the heavy Bretonian fighter Crusader being sold at the following locations:

> Battleship Norfolk, Cambridge System, Bretonia Space
>
> Battleship Suffolk, New London System, Bretonia Space
>
> Battleship York, Leeds System, Bretonia Space
>
> Battleship Essex, Dublin System, Bretonia Space

Comment: Cant find it in Leeds system!